# Is it ok to unit-test an abstract class by instantiating it as a mock object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, mocking, abstract-class

It has come to my attention that you can unit-test an abstract class by instantiating it as a mock object. Thereby you mock the abstract properties and methods, while being able to test the implemented ones.

However, I am accustomed to distinguish between the class **to test** and the injected dependencies **to mock/stub**. So, in this early stage of my new enlightenment I wonder if there are any pitfalls to this way of testing?? Any thoughts on this?

Regards, 
Morten

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An abstract class, to be of any value, should have concrete subclasses which can be instantiated. So unit test those, and via them implicitly the base class.

If it has no concrete subclasses, I can't think of any reason why it should exist (as an abstract class, that is).

In general, I prefer to use mocking only to set up the *environment* of the class to be tested, not to instantiate the class itself. This distinction - to me - keeps the test cases clearer, and ensures that I always test the real functionality of the class.

Of course, I can think of cases (with legacy code) when the main issue is to be able to write unit tests somehow, anyhow, to enable refactoring (as discussed in [*Working Effectively with Legacy Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)). As a temporary solution in such cases, (almost) anything goes. But once the unit tests are working, the class should be refactored properly asap to make it clean and testable (and its unit tests too, to make them maintainable).

Comment: It may be part of a framework and is inherited by the user of the library - but the library doesn't provide a concrete implementation.

Comment: @Stefan, how would such a class be used then without actually being subclassed? Btw IMHO a well designed library should expose interfaces, not abstract classes. Unless when such abstract classes are meant to be reused for *subclassing* (e.g. `Abstract*` in the Collection framework).

Comment: @Péter: no, that's not true. For instance, in our application, we have a platform which provides many baseclasses which are inherited and extended by modules. The platform is tested on its own, of course it doesn't have any relation to modules.

Comment: @Peter, the distinguishing between the tested and the test input was also the reason why i posted this question. On the other hand: If you test the abstract class, you can ignore it when testing objects that inherrit it. Isn't that a tad more DRY?

Comment: @Stefan, OK, I get your point. Even in that case, I would prefer testing a "basic" default subclass for the platform (even implemented in the test realm), rather than mocking it. That in turn also verifies that your class design is working well, i.e. that your abstract class is indeed subclassable in a coherent and consistent fashion.

Comment: @Morten, hmmm, good question. I usually prefer to err on the side of having too many unit tests rather than sticking to DRY too strictly. As in a subclass I always test the synergy of the base and subclass implementation, which can go awry in unexpected ways if either the base or subclass is implemented improperly, I would usually prefer fully testing all subclasses (unless their actual content is trivial). But indeed, with a huge number of subclasses, that may be too tedious. The duplication could be potentially eliminated though via e.g. extraction to a common test base class.

Comment: @Péter: Yes, I would subclass it too. See my answer.

Comment: Assembly is one of the abstract classes that exist without concrete implementation

Comment: @DanHunex, what about [AssemblyBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using inheritance to combine two classes, see if you can use composition.

So instead of this:

```
abstract class PaySalary {
    payAmount(decimal money) {
        if (transferAmount(money)) {
            isPaid = true;
        }
    }

    abstract void transferAmount(decimal money);
}
```

Do this:

```
class PaySalary {
    public MoneyTransferrer;

    payAmount(decimal money) {
        if (MoneyTransferrer.transferAmount(money)) {
            isPaid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to inherit the class in your unit test, but you can simply mock a MoneyTransferrer. You can also test the MoneyTransferrer without depending on the base class.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to test abstract classes -- not how  avoid inheriting from an abstract class. I'm interested in a best practice for testing abstract classes for situations where this is necessary :-)

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't a concrete implementation in the part I'm testing, I usually write a test-implementation. In the unit test I do something similar as the user of my classes does. If he inherits my class, I inherit in the test.

On the other side, I wouldn't say that it is bad to use a mock framework to create an implementation. In my cases I usually doesn't work, usually because I need to write ORM mapping files for that class and thing like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you will test an abstract class much like you test an interface with injection.**

If you write a test for `ILog` and inject it for testing using `MockLog` then you would do the same for `LogBase` (which is an abstract class in this example) and inject it with `MockLog` just the same.

An `abstract class` is NOT an `interface` BUT they are used much the same from overhead.

Answer (score -1):

An [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) is by definition, abstract. There shouldn't be anything to test if it's truly abstract.

Comment: @Jon: Sounds like you're talking about an interface, an abstract class has functionality (which could need testing if it includes logic), but cannot be instantiated directly, only derived from.

Comment: If there is nothing concrete in an abstract class, isn't it just an interface?

Comment: @Jackson, but if you have no concrete subclasses for your abstract class, what's the point of its existence?

Comment: @Peter: I'd imagine he's got an abstract class that has functionality shared between two or more concrete classes. He can test that functionality using the concrete classes, or alternatively test the abstract class directly. If there are no concrete classes then the abstract class is redundant.

Comment: I had always thought an abstract class was an interface, but it seems at least in C# terminology you can include concrete/shared functionality. I stand corrected!

Comment: What you mean is a *pure virtual class*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type